# What type of camera does this "Vivitar 75-205MM" lens fit?

Tags: lens, minolta, vivitar

I was wondering if anyone could help me out. Does anyone know what camera this lens would fit? It doesn't fit my Canon EOS Rebel T1i. A friend got it for me, not knowing it wouldn't fit.

Thank you in advance.

*Links go to larger versions of the lens pictures*
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since the letters "MC" are stamped on the ID ring along with the other information I would think it is a Minolta MC/MD mount lens. Even if the "MC" stand for "multi-Coated" and was printed on the lens for all of the various mounts for which it was made, the "MC" led me to compare it to the Minolta mount.

The bayonets match up with the Minolta pattern as does the "notch" in the bayonet opposite the aperture linkage lever. The only difference between the photo in the OP and the photo of a Minolta MD mount lens below is the direction in which the lens is oriented. They're both the same mount.

[image: Minolta MC/MD SR mount]

Comment: For whatever pedantic 2¢ this adds, I can confirm that some Vivitar lenses for Pentax are also marked "MC".

Answer (score -2):

It looks like an old Nikon mount before the days of electronics in the lenses. It is  macro zoom manual focus.  Good for portraits now. Nice find and a great lens in its day. Just google it.

Comment: Nikon aperture levers are just inside one of the bayonet lugs, not between them as with this lens.

Comment: @John H. Jensen, I tried but I can't seem to find one like this to get info

Comment: Just Google _what_ exactly?

Comment: That's what I was wanting to know what do I type in the search bar of google?