# What is the mount on this Exakta 100-500mm f/5.6-8 MC Macro lens?

Tags: lens, lens-mount, lens-adapter, adapter

I recently bought, second-hand and for a few euros, the following:

- adapter Exakta to Sony e-mount
- an Exakta 100-500mm 1:5.6-8 MC Macro lens, made in Japan

Strangely, the lens does not fit on the adapter.

Which kind of adapter do I need? I don't find any indication of the lens mount.

Inner diameters of the respective mounts:

- lens: 38 mm
- adapter: 37.5 mm

**Adapter:**
[image: Adapter]

**Lens:**
[image: Lens]

**Lens, again:**
[image: Show me your face, little lens]

Comment: It looks like a Minolta SR mount on the lens. Not all Exakta lenses are built with EXA mount.

Comment: A full frontal image of the mount might help to identify it.

Comment: By the way, you've got some serious dirt on the lens, or maybe fungus growing in it.

Comment: I've cleaned it after taking the photos above. Looks good to me, like the other lenses I have. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What type of camera does this "Vivitar 75-205MM" lens fit?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/83970/what-type-of-camera-does-this-vivitar-75-205mm-lens-fit)

Comment: Yeah, it would have been nice if the Japanese manufacturers would not have copied (Eastern) German lens brands...^^ It can be confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely a **Minolta SR** mount, also called **Minolta MD** sometimes.

For comparison you can see the mount of my Minolta MD Rokkor 45/2.0 lens:

[image: Mount of Minolta MD Rokkor 45/2.0]

The gap in the metal on the left and the pin on the right side are characteristic. The pin is ~4 mm higher than the surrounding metal ring  of the mount.

The outer diameter of the thin bright metal ring is 42mm (without the "wings"), the inner diameter of the dark metal is 36mm.

There are MD-SonyE (or MD-NEX) adapters available. I don't have any E-mount cameras and no adapter for E-mount. 
Instead I attach it directly on a bellow or I put is on my A77II using a MD-Sony-A Adapter.

Comment: Thank you for helping a novice lens buyer! Until now, I only bought some that were made for Sony E-mount. Thanks to those adapters, I can look around for good, old but less expensive lenses.